# immutable record getIn fails in ie10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, babeljs, immutable.js

Here is the immutable record class definition

```
import Immutable, {Record} from 'immutable';

const FEATURE_DEFAULTS = {
  name: null,
};

export class Feature extends Record(FEATURE_DEFAULTS) { 
}
```

An instance is initialised this way:

```
const featureName = 'a value';
const b = new Feature({ name: featureName });

console.log(b.getIn(['name']));
```

In most modern browsers (chrome, safari etc), it works. It prints out the value in the `name` field as expected.

However in ie10, `b.getIn(['name'])` throw this exception: `Unable to get property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined or null reference`

[image]

More info about my project, it uses these dependencies

```
"immutable": "^3.8.1",
"react": "^15.1.0",
"react-chartist": "^0.10.1",
"react-dom": "^15.1.0",
"react-intl": "2.1.2",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^2.4.1",
"redux": "^3.5.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
"reselect": "^2.5.1",
```

I am also using `babel` to translate es6 syntax

```
"babel-core": "^6.9.1",
"babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"babel-register": "^6.9.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
```

How can I fixed this issue?

EDIT:
I think the exception is thrown from here:
https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/38019326a8d006a45ef48d9c4644e23ea476d298/src/Record.js#L55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution from babel's bug tracker https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T3041

Basically the steps are:

- npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
- npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classe
- Add these plugins to `.babelrc`:

  ```
    "plugins": [
         "transform-class-properties",
         ['transform-es2015-classes', {loose: true}]
       ]
  ```